# Discuss the solution of the linear system in terms of real parameter $a$

Tags: linear-algebra

I got this assignment, and I tried to solve it, but I am not sure whether any more steps should be taken to prove my conclusions or have I gotten far enough. The system in question is the following one:
$$
x-y+2z=1\\
2x+ay+z=a\\
2x-y+a^2z=a^2
$$
I started by writing the system as an augmented matrix:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-1&2&1\\
2&a&1&a\\
2&-1&a^2&a^2
\end{array}\right]
$$
Then I began reducing it:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-1&2&1\\
2&-1&a^2&a^2\\
2&a&1&a
\end{array}\right]
\rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-1&2&1\\
0&1&a^2-4&a^2-2\\
0&a+2&-3&a-2
\end{array}\right]
$$
And I arrived to this form:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&a^2-2&a^2-1\\
0&1&a^2-4&a^2-2\\
0&0&-3-(a+2)(a^2-4)&a-2-(a+2)(a^2-2)
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, since getting it into reduced row echelon form would be pretty simple at this point, but would also result in a lot of big polynomial fractions I don't really want to handle, do I need to do so or can I just draw conclusions about the solutions of the system from the last row? This is my reasoning, and the part I'm not sure about.

I first consider the first polynomial($-3-(a+2)(a^2-4)$), and see what happens when it is or isn't equal to zero:

1. If the first polynomial isn't equal to zero, I can divide the last row by it, getting a matrix in reduced echelon row, showing that the system has a unique solution.
2. If the first polynomial is equal to zero, then the number of solutions depends on the value of the second polynomial.

   1. If the second polynomial is equal to zero as well, the last row is equivalent to the equation $0=0$, leaving me with only two equations in a system with three unknowns, meaning the system has infinitely many solutions.
   2. If the second polynomial isn't equal to zero, the last row is equivalent to an equation such as $0=1$, which is a contradiction, meaning the system has no solution.

Now, to calculate the exact values of $a$ for which each of these situations occurs:

I'll first calculate the roots of the first polynomial:
$$
-3-(a+2)(a^2-4)=0
$$
I get:
$$
a_1=-1, a_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{21}}{2}, a_3=\frac{-1-\sqrt{21}}{2}
$$
Then I need to check for which of these three values the second polynomial is zero as well. Instead of solving another cubic equation, I'll solve the following equation, in order to get the values for which both polynomials have the same value:
$$
-3-(a+2)(a^2-4)=a-2-(a+2)(a^2-2)\\
-a^3-2a^2+4a+5=-a^3-2a^2+3a+2\\
4a+5=3a+2\\
4a-3a=2-5\\
a=-3
$$
Comparing this result with the one from the previous equation, I conclude that the polynomials will never both be equal to zero for the same value of $a$.

So, my final conclusion based on all of the above is this: the linear system will have no solution for $a\in\{-1, \frac{-1+\sqrt{21}}{2}, \frac{-1-\sqrt{21}}{2}\}$, and will have a unique solution for every other $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Please point out any mistakes you see in either my calculations or my reasoning, and tell me how to do it properly.

Comment: Here's a small tip: you don't actually have to solve for the zero set of the second polynomial.  You said yourself that you're only concerned about the common zeroes of the first and second polynomial, so once you've got your three zeroes of the first polynomial, all you have to do is plug them into the second polynomial and see if you get zero as a result or you if you don't.

Comment: Find the determinant of$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&-1&2\\
2&a&1\\
2&-1&a^2
\end{array}\right]$ which is equal to $(a+1)(a^2+a-5)$ and you could discuss other way.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct. The main part of this explanation is to show that $f(a) = -3 - (a + 2)(a^2 - 4) \neq 0$ because that would imply that $0z = a - 2 -(a + 2)(a^2 - 3)$ and since the right side is only $0$ for $a = 3$(which you solved) it follows that $a$ cannot be any of the roots of $f(a)$.